# Include Counter in array JSONata

Tags: arrays, json, counter, jsonata

I just started using JSONata and I found it quite fascinating to parse JSON easily. But I have this problem, and I'm not sure if it can be done with JSONata directly.

I want to include a counter that goes from 1 to "the number of objects in an array", like so:

Original output from JSONata expression:

[
  {
    "a": false,
    "b": "",
    "c": "",
    "d": true
  },
  {
    "a": false,
    "b": "",
    "c": "",
    "d": true
  },
  {
    "a": false,
    "b": "",
    "c": "",
    "d": true
  }
]

Wanted output:

[
  {
    "count": "1",
    "a": false,
    "b": "",
    "c": "",
    "d": true
  },
  {
    "count": "2",
    "a": false,
    "b": "",
    "c": "",
    "d": true
  },
  {
    "count": "3",
    "a": false,
    "b": "",
    "c": "",
    "d": true
  }
]

Is it possible? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [$map()](http://docs.jsonata.org/higher-order-functions.html#maparray-function) function to iterate over a list and apply an expression to each item.  The second argument of your function will be the index within the array.  So for your example, the following will merge the `count` property into your original array of objects:

```
$ ~> $map(function($v, $i) {
  $merge([{'count': $i+1}, $v])
})
```

See this working in the JSONata Exerciser: http://try.jsonata.org/rkDpyXMVM

Comment: Thank you very much Andrew, that was exactly what I needed!